# How to change content of SwiftUI menu if option was pressed during tap

Tags: macos, swiftui

I would like to create a SwiftUI Menu that has a dynamic content (very easy to do), but I would like to sort the items if the option-key was pressed when the Menu was clicked. I have explored using gestures, but I can’t figure out how to change my state from the gesture in a way that won’t interfere with the operation of the Menu itself.

Is there a way to update a State variable based on tap+modifier key, that will occur before the Menu subviews are created, and won’t interfere with the normal operation of the Menu?

The Menu will have “recents” and might contain a few dozen entries.  Being able to sort the history will make it faster to find a specific entry.  I want to use a Menu because it’s very compact when not engaged.

The skeleton of what I am looking for is:

```
Menu("My Menu") {
    if <option-key pressed?> {
        // sorted  order
        Button("A") { }
        Button("B") { }
        Button("C") { }
        Button("D") { }
    } else {
        // natural order
        Button("B") { }
        Button("D") { }
        Button("A") { }
        Button("C") { }
    }
}
```

This is for MacOS, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to update a State variable based on tap+modifier key, that will occur before the Menu subviews are created, and won’t interfere with the normal operation of the Menu? -> So you want to update a variable with a tap before the view of it was created. But also you want it to not mess with the "normal" menu. Please be more specific

Comment: When I click on the menu, the views inside of it are displayed in the order listed.   But when the user clicks, while holding the “Option” key pressed, I want to change the behavior of the menu.  I want to generate the items in sorted order.    I can do the sort, I just need to have a State variable set so that I can use an if/else to provide the views in sorted order.   I can only if/else on a State variable, so that’s what I’m looking to set.  Unless there is some clever way to catch the Option key being pressed I am unfamliar with.

Comment: Using AppKit this would be very easy, but I’m trying to stay in the confines of SwiftUI.

Comment: I have recently tried @GestureState and gestures, but  have had no luck.